# Maximizing the trace of $AB(B+A^{-1})^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, trace

Given that $A=\text{diag}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is a diagonal matrix (this we fix) with positive values and $B=\text{diag}(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ is a another diagonal matrix (this we get to choose) with positive values, I know that

\begin{align*}
\text{Tr} \left( A B \left( B + A^{-1} \right)^{-1} \right)
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i^2}{a_i+b_i^{-1}}
\end{align*}

is maximised when $b_i$'s (these are also the eigenvalues) are maximized, which further imply that $\text{Tr}(B)$ (these are also the sum of eigenvales) is maximized. Is this still true if $B$ is just a general positive definite matrix (i.e., Is $\text{Tr}(AB(B+A^{-1})^{-1})$ maximized when $\text{Tr}(B)$ is maximized -- note that $A$ remains fixed)? (Note that $A$ is still a diagonal matrix with positive values.)

Comment: Are we still given that $A$ is diagonal with positive values?

Comment: Yup, we are. I will make it clearer in my ques -- thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say that "the expression is maximized when the $b_i$'s are maximized". It doesn't make sense to talk about "maximizing" the $b_i$'s without some kind of constraint.

Comment: @BenGrossmann:  I think what the OP is getting at is that if we define $f(B) = \text{Tr}(AB(B+A^{-1})^{-1})$, then $\partial f/\partial b_i > 0$.  But it's not clear to me how to adapt this observation to a non-diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observation that I think you have in mind is as follows. For diagonal matrices $B = \operatorname{diag}(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ and $C = \operatorname{diag}(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ and the function
$$
f(B) = \operatorname{tr}(AB(B + A)^{-1}),
$$
it holds that if $b_i \geq c_i > 0$ for all $i$, then $f(B) \geq f(C)$. One natural extension of this property would be that for positive definite matrices $B\succeq C$ (i.e. $B - C$ is positive semidefinite), it holds that $f(B) \geq f(C)$. As it turns out, this result does hold.

First, note that we can rewrite
$$
\begin{align}
AB(B + A^{-1})^{-1} &= AB(A^{-1}[A + B^{-1}]B)^{-1}
\\ & = ABB^{-1}(A + B^{-1})^{-1}A
\\ &= A(A + B^{-1})^{-1}A.
\end{align}
$$
Now, it's easier to see that if $B$ is positive definite, then this expression (namely $A(A + B^{-1})^{-1}A$) is positive definite. Note that
$$
B \succeq C \implies\\
B^{-1} \preceq C^{-1} \implies\\
A + B^{-1} \preceq A + C^{-1} \implies\\
(A + B^{-1})^{-1} \succeq (A + C^{-1})^{-1} \implies\\
A(A + B^{-1})^{-1}A \succeq A(A + C^{-1})^{-1}A.
$$
It follows that
$$
f(B) = \operatorname{tr}[A(A + B^{-1})^{-1}A] \geq \operatorname{tr}[A(A + C^{-1})^{-1}A] = f(C),
$$
which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: It seems that you did not even have to use the property of $A$ being a diagonal matrix with positive entries. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: @Resu The only necessary property of $A$ for the reasoning applied here is that $A$ is symmetric and inveritble, which follows from $A$ being diagonal with positive entries.

Comment: I see, that's impressive. Thank you.

Comment: @Resu Actually, I misspoke: the step $A + B^{-1} \preceq A + C^{-1} \implies
(A + B^{-1})^{-1} \succeq (A + C^{-1})^{-1}$ requires that $A + B^{-1}$ is positive definite. One way to ensure that this occurs is to say that $A$ must also be positive definite (which again, holds if $A$ is diagonal with positive diagonal entries).

Comment: Yup, sounds reasonable. Thanks.